# Multiprocessing pool example (parallel) is slower than sequential. Trying to understand pool in python

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing

I have been reading and trying to understand how to run python faster with multiprocessing. I found this example: [multiprocessing.Pool example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413821/multiprocessing-pool-example).

I then made up this test and ran in a server with 8 cores.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    map(f, [x for x in range(1000000)])
    print("Sequential run time: %.2f seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))

    start_time = time.time()
    p = Pool(8)
    p.map(f, [x for x in range(1000000)])
    print("Parallel run time: %.2f seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

However, results were slower when using `Pool`

output

```
Sequential run time: 0.13 seconds
Parallel run time: 0.98 seconds
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, except *perhaps* running more processes than you have physical cores to run them on - can't guess from here whether you *have* at least 8 cores available to run the 8 processes you created.

But even if you do, the time taken to compute one `f(x)` result is trivial compared to all the overheads of passing the arguments to, and passing the results back from, the worker processes - `f()` does very little work.  IPC (inter-process communication) isn't cheap.

That's why the docs stress repeatedly to do as little IPC as possible.  You're not going to get any overall speedup (to the contrary, as you've found) if the useful work done per function call is tiny.

BTW, this:

```
[x for x in range(1000000)]
```

is better written as plain:

```
range(1000000)
```

although making that change makes no difference to the real points here.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I have a much larger function... I wonder if it would work in loops with long lists

Comment: To demonstrate that the overhead on the multiprocessing solution is responsible for making it slower, you can change the line `map(f, range(1000000))` to `Pool(1).map(range(1000000))`. This will make the first run slower when compared to the second (on my machine, it was 0.59s vs 0.46s).

Comment: Indeed. Thanks a lot @MatheusMarchini