# Python chess multiprocessing, no speed gaining

Tags: python, performance, process, multiprocessing, chess

I`m trying to write a chess game in python, it`s almost complete, and I would like to use multiprocessing to speed up my program, but what I have done it has quite the opposite effect ;D
Original process run main, it supervise all game processes, and provides responsiveness
First added process runs choosing move algorythm.
and to speed up choosing best move, I divided all possible moves for 2 lists, and I`m running them in 2 new processes.
So finally, i have 4 processes, my pc cpu has 4 cores 8 thread, but time of finding best move increased in comparison to using only 2 processes -> one original to supervise the game, and one additional to find best moves alone.

part of code with 2 processes(finding best move):

```
def find_best_move(cre_gs: object(), valid_moves: list, queue) -> object():
    # random.shuffle(valid_moves)
    global next_move
    find_nega_max_move_alpha_beta(cre_gs, DEPTH, valid_moves, 1 if cre_gs.white_to_move else -1, -checkmate, checkmate)
    queue.put(next_move)

def find_nega_max_move_alpha_beta(cre_gs: object(), depth: int, valid_moves: list, turn_multiplier: int, alpha: int, beta: int) -> int:
    global next_move
    if depth == 0:
        return turn_multiplier * score_material(cre_gs)

    max_score = -checkmate
    for move in valid_moves:
        cre_gs.make_move(move)
        next_moves = cre_gs.get_valid_moves()
        score = -find_nega_max_move_alpha_beta(cre_gs, depth - 1, next_moves, -turn_multiplier, -beta, -alpha)
        cre_gs.undo_move()

        if score > max_score:
            max_score = score
            if depth == DEPTH:
                next_move = move

        if max_score > alpha:
            alpha = max_score
        if alpha >= beta:
            break
    return max_score


def score_material(cre_gs: object()) -> int:
    if cre_gs.checkmate:
        if cre_gs.white_to_move:
            return checkmate
        else:
            return -checkmate
    score = 0
    for row in cre_gs.board:
        for square in row:
            if square[0] == 'w':
                score += piece_score[square[1]]
            elif square[0] == 'b':
                score -= piece_score[square[1]]
    return score
```

part of code with 4 processes(finding best move):

```
def find_best_move(cre_gs: object(), valid_moves: list, queue) -> object():
    # random.shuffle(valid_moves)
    start_time = time.time()
    global next_move
    process_1_moves = valid_moves[0: len(valid_moves) // 2]
    process_2_moves = valid_moves[len(valid_moves) // 2::]
    return_queue_1 = Queue()
    return_queue_2 = Queue()

    process_1 = Process(target=find_best_move_process, args=(cre_gs, process_1_moves, return_queue_1))
    process_2 = Process(target=find_best_move_process, args=(cre_gs, process_2_moves, return_queue_2))
    process_1.start()
    process_2.start()
    print(cpu_count())
    process_1.join()
    print('1.joined', time.time() - start_time)
    process_2.join()
    print('2.joined', time.time() - start_time)

    move_1 = return_queue_1.get()
    move_2 = return_queue_2.get()

    if not process_1.is_alive() and not process_2.is_alive():
        find_nega_max_move_alpha_beta(cre_gs, DEPTH, [move_1, move_2], 1 if cre_gs.white_to_move else -1, -checkmate, checkmate)
        queue.put(next_move)
        print('all.joined', time.time() - start_time)

def find_best_move_process(cre_gs: object(), valid_moves: list, queue) -> object():
    global next_move
    find_nega_max_move_alpha_beta(cre_gs, DEPTH, valid_moves, 1 if cre_gs.white_to_move else -1, -checkmate, checkmate)
    queue.put(next_move)

def find_nega_max_move_alpha_beta(cre_gs: object(), depth: int, valid_moves: list, turn_multiplier: int, alpha: int, beta: int) -> int:
    global next_move
    if depth == 0:
        return turn_multiplier * score_material(cre_gs)

    max_score = -checkmate
    for move in valid_moves:
        cre_gs.make_move(move)
        next_moves = cre_gs.get_valid_moves()
        score = -find_nega_max_move_alpha_beta(cre_gs, depth - 1, next_moves, -turn_multiplier, -beta, -alpha)
        cre_gs.undo_move()

        if score > max_score:
            max_score = score
            if depth == DEPTH:
                next_move = move

        if max_score > alpha:
            alpha = max_score
        if alpha >= beta:
            break
    return max_score


def score_material(cre_gs: object()) -> int:
    if cre_gs.checkmate:
        if cre_gs.white_to_move:
            return checkmate
        else:
            return -checkmate
    score = 0
    for row in cre_gs.board:
        for square in row:
            if square[0] == 'w':
                score += piece_score[square[1]]
            elif square[0] == 'b':
                score -= piece_score[square[1]]
    return score
```

time of running algorithm for first 3 moves:
2 processes: 2.71,  2.41,  6.86
4 processes: 3.49,  3.43,  14.89

I wonder why is that happened, and how I may speed up this algorithm?
If multiprocessing Process isnt here appropriate, what should I use?
Thanks in advance for any advice ;)

Comment: Your code is complex.  Since you already have a list of moves and you want to compute against all of them, use [multiprocessing.Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413821/multiprocessing-pool-example) to simplify.

Comment: I'd say there are many things you could do to speed up this code without the use of using multiprocessing which is very complicated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).